# Add value of input field to anchor/link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to append/add the value of an input field entered by the to an anchor/link tag on the same page, that links to an external website.

```
<input type="text" name="foo">
<a id="uniqueId" href="http://example.com/{value of foo}">Click</a>
```

I think I need to use jQuery for this, but have no idea on how to use it in this case. Does any one have any toughts on this matter?

btw amd for security reasons the value does also need to be url encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, with jQuery:

```js
$('input[name="foo"]').on('change', function(){
        var self = this,
            $self = $(self),
            link = $self.next();
        link.prop('href', function(){
            this.href = this.protocol + '//' + this.hostname + '/' + encodeURIComponent(self.value);
        });
    });
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (' attr(href) ')';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo">
<a href="http://example.com/{value of foo}">
```

In response to the question, asked in the comments:

> One question, Can you adapt your awnser to add a unique identifier to the anchor tag `<a id="uniqueId" href="">Click</a>`?. Forgot to add this to the question

The answer is, of course, 'yes,' and it's rather simple (and more reliable than relying on the structure of the HTML and traversal), simply select the element based on its `id`:

```
$('input[name="foo"]').on('change', function(){
        var self = this,
            link = $('#uniqueId');
        link.prop('href', function(){
            this.href = this.protocol + '//' + this.hostname + encodeURIComponent(self.value);
        });
    });
```

```js
$('input[name="foo"]').on('change', function(){
        var self = this,
            link = $('#uniqueId');
        link.prop('href', function(){
            this.href = this.protocol + '//' + this.hostname + '/' + encodeURIComponent(self.value);
        });
    });
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (' attr(href) ')';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo">
<a id="uniqueId" href="http://example.com/{value of foo}">
```

Incidentally, with plain JavaScript this is still (of course) quite possible:

```
function appendValueToAnchor () {
  var link = document.getElementById('uniqueId'),
      protocol = link.protocol,
      newValue = encodeURIComponent( this.value );
  link.href = protocol + '//' + link.hostname + '/' + newValue;
}

var input = document.querySelector('input[name="foo"]');

input.addEventListener('change', appendValueToAnchor);
```

```js
function appendValueToAnchor () {
  var link = document.getElementById('uniqueId'),
      protocol = link.protocol,
      newValue = encodeURIComponent( this.value );
  link.href = protocol + '//' + link.hostname + '/' + newValue;
}

var input = document.querySelector('input[name="foo"]');

input.addEventListener('change', appendValueToAnchor);
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (' attr(href) ')';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo">
<a id="uniqueId" href="http://example.com/{value of foo}">
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: One question, Can you adapt your awnser to add a unique identifier to the anchor tag `<a id="uniqueId" href="">Click</a>`?. Forgot to add this to the question. And it regards an external domain, not my own

Comment: Thanks but sorry I just realized that I also forgot to mention in the OP that it links to an external domain :S sorry for the confusion, did not realize to add it.

Comment: That doesn't matter; we're retrieving the `hostname` of the link itself, we're not doing anything at all to violate the cross-origin policy or suchlike.

Comment: I could not get the jQuery solution to work, but that is not requiered, your plain javascript solution works like a charm, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! But, that said, does the jQuery 'not work' in your own site/project, or does it not work *here* (once you've clicked on the 'Show code snippet' and 'Run code snippet')? Note that I updated all the snippets, a few moments ago, to add in the location protocol (which I forgot initially, in all but the plain-JavaScript solution).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this

```
$('[name=foo]').blur(function(){
   $('a').attr("href", encodeURIComponent("http://domain.com/" + $(this).val()));
});
```

The above will assign the value once the input loses the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following

```
$(function(){

    $('input[name=foo]').on("change",function(){

        var $input = $(this); 
        $('#uniqueId').prop("href","http://example.com/"+$input.val());
        });

    });
});

<input type="text" name="foo"></input>
<a id="uniqueId" href="http://example.com/{value of foo}">Click</a>
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

My use case is slightly different in that rather than relying on manual input, appending two links on a page with a value stored hidden form field.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33694573)